# GPS tracker android thread

Tags: android, android-volley, android-gps

I was trying to make a thread able to send, constantly, GPS coordinate to my DB.
This is my code:

```
public class trackThread extends Thread {
    Context mContext;
    public trackThread(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public void run() {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        trackThread.MyCurrentLoctionListener locationListener = new trackThread.MyCurrentLoctionListener();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    }



    public class MyCurrentLoctionListener implements android.location.LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            final String myLocation = "Latitude = " + location.getLatitude() + " Longitude = " + location.getLongitude();



            // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
            String url ="http://example.org/send.php?lat=" + location.getLatitude() + "&long=" + location.getLongitude();

            // Request a string response from the provided URL.
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.


                            Log.e("Response is: "+ response.toString(), myLocation);
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("That didn't work!", myLocation);
                }
            });

            // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
            queue.add(stringRequest);
            Log.e("La risposta è ", stringRequest.toString());


        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }
    }

}
```

This thread is called in this method located in a Java Class:

```
public void inviaGps(View v) {
    if ((ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) ||  ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

        Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "Devi abilitare i permessi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.show();
        return;
    }
    trackThread p = new trackThread(getApplicationContext());
    new Thread(p).start();
}
```

this method is triggered by the click on a button of a simple and common activity.

I think that the problem is caused by the wrong usage of context (sorry, I'm not so expert in Android coding).
P.S.: I also tried to add a simple Log.e below `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates()` to debug and try to understand the problem. It has been displayed to me

Comment: It does not work well. Well what is it that goes wrong?

Comment: You're right. The problem is that the method onLocationChanged is called and invoked but it doesn't work properly

Comment: Where do you create and start that text?  With which context?

Comment: You still did not tell what it is that does not work proper.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited it. Tell me if it is clear. However thank you

Comment: You should be making a service that sends coords to DB. Its similar code with bonus service can run when app is closed.  If you used the fused provider you can specify the time interval or min distance for the next coordinate.  With fused provider you get a location and write to DB simple.

Comment: No. You still didnot tell what problem you have.

Comment: I click on the button that should invoke inviaGps, then trackThread, run, and finally onLocationChanged. It doesn't work because, even though I moved my smartphone, no coordinates has been sent to my DB...

Comment: `, even though I moved my smartphone, no coordinates has been sent to my DB...` Well maybe you send them wrong? But is sending to a database relevant? Doesnt it all start with `onLocationChanged()` getting triggered by the listener? You should inform us about that to begin with.

Comment: I'm sure that the operations realted to the DB are corrects. It all start with onLocationChanged() that, as you said, should be triggered by the listener.